# How to convert boost::date_time::date::day_of_week() to string type?

Tags: c++, boost

Here's what i want to do.

```
ptime now = second_clock::local_time();
date today = now.date();
today.day_of_week();
string day = "Sat";
if(day == to_string(today.day_of_week()))
{
   //perform an action
}
else
{
   //perform another action
}
```

The code compiles but the program never executes the if block. How else can i convert day_of_week() to string?

Comment: `day_of_week` return a number, converting it to a string will give you that number as a string. You could use e.g. an `std::unordered_map` to map the number to a string.

Comment: `std::stringstream`? Or do you want to convert the number to the day string (as an example to Monday)?

Comment: @skypjack boost::date::day_of_week() is supposed to return the Day of week. I need the day of week so i can compare it to data retrieved from a db and schedule an action. I used day_of_week because i couldn't find any other way of getting it from the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest `boost::lexical_cast<>` here:

```
std::string day = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(today.day_of_week());
```

Or simply:

```
std::cout << today.day_of_week();
```

**<kbd>[Live On C++ Shell](http://cpp.sh/32qo)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main() {
    auto now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
    auto today = now.date();

    std::string day = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(today.day_of_week());
    std::cout << today.day_of_week();
}
```

Prints

```
Fri
```

Comment: coliru and wandbox seem down... No live sample for now :( **Edit** Well, waddyaknow, http://cpp.sh/32qo works too :)

Comment: Hi @sehe, can I get name based on locale?. I mean by language like `de_DE.utf-8`